# DNS not working on AD DC

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I am an IT student setting up AD on a small computer lab. The lab's workstations are all connected to a switch, along with a server running Windows Server 2008 R2. I have installed AD DS and DNS on the server, and all the workstations are connected to the domain.

My problem is that I can't push out Group Policy changes on any computer except the server. The workstations and the server can ping each other, but gpupdate says it can't find the DC. I checked Server Manager and found many DNS errors; it seems that almost none of the AD DNS records were created.

I have uploaded the errors from the Best Practices Analyzer on both the [AD DS](http://pastebin.com/hcy1nHwF) and the [DNS server](http://pastebin.com/RKmQcpFC). I also have the results from ipconfig and dcdiag if you need them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1 AD server, then set the DNS settings on the NIC to only 127.0.0.1. If you have more than 1 AD server, the first DNS server on the NIC should be another AD server and the second DNS server should be 127.0.0.1.

Then on your workstations, set the DNS settings to only the IP address of your domain controller(s). Do not list any additional DNS servers.

If your server and workstations need internet access, then in DNS manager on your servers, add a forwarder with an outside DNS server.

Comment: I have made these changes, but it still won't go through. Judging from the error reports, there are many DNS records that are missing on the server. There is only one SOA and one NS record for each forward lookup zone.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you said there are only SOA and ND records. It sounds like you have you DNS server configured as a stub zone. Right-click the zone under `Forward Lookup Zones` and pick Properties. On the General tab, click Change next to Type. Set your zone type to Primary and check the box at the bottom for `Store the zone in Active Directory`.

Comment: All the zones were already Primary and stored in AD. I noticed that the NS records had no IP in them, so I set them to the server's IP and restarted the server. Now the zones are populated with records, but the best practices scan says that the domain controller has not registered its A/AAAA records. I still can't get gpupdate to complete successfully.